# PHP String for HTML style

Tags: php, html, css, string

I want to show a png file in background of a div. I have this CSS style for put it in the correct place. I'v tested directly in my HTML and the style works properly. I't doesn't work wen I use php variable.

```
<?php 

    if ($RScoluna1['nova'] == 1){
        $style = "background-image:url(layout/nova.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: 220px 0;";
    } else {
        $style = "";
    }


    ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $row_RScoluna1['class_cor']; ?>" style="<?php echo $style; ?>">
```

Comment: are you sure that $RScoluna1['nova'] sometimes holds 1 as a value?

Comment: yes my first data row have 1 (mySQL INT)

Comment: Make sure the relative path to the image is working and the div has enough width and heigth to display the image.

Comment: Check the path of the files.

Comment: I'v checked. If you copy 
background-image:url(layout/nova.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: 220px 0;
and past it on
style="" it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy pasted

```
background-image:url(layout/nova.png)
```

from a css file, then you should fix the path accordingly to the position of the script.

In example:

```
background-image:url("../css/layout/nova.png");
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: My bad.

if ($RScoluna1['nova'] == 1){

should be 

if ($row_RScoluna1['nova'] == 1){